# CCTV broadcast using Port Triggering?

Tags: port-forwarding

I don't see any port-forwarding in my ADSL admin page but I see port-triggering.

Can I use port-triggering to broadcast my CCTV feed so I can view it in vMEye app?

I also try to open a port using port-triggering and check it via canyouseeme.org, but it says "Connection timeout".

Comment: if you router can do port triggering chances are good it also can do port forwarding (the functionality is needed for port triggering), they probably just call it another name. What make and model is your router?

Comment: Prolink https://pldthome.com/images/default-source/dsl/dsl-upgrades-wifimodem.png?sfvrsn=0